# Surface curl of a vector tangent to a surface is zero?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, surfaces, vector-fields, riemann-surfaces

The surface gradient operator $\nabla_\Gamma$ is defined as $\nabla_\Gamma =  \nabla - \mathbf{n(n} \cdot \nabla)$, where $\Gamma$ is a surface.

The surface curl operator on a vector tangent to $\Gamma$ is defined as $ \nabla_\Gamma \times [] = \{ \nabla_\Gamma \cdot (\mathbf{n} \times []) \} \mathbf{n}$.

Let $\mathbf{P}$ be a tangent vector to a surface $\Gamma$. The surface curl of $\mathbf{P}$ is as follows:

$ \nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} \\
= [\nabla_\Gamma \cdot (\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{P})]\mathbf{n} \\
= [(\nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{n}) \cdot \mathbf{P} - (\nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} )\cdot \mathbf{n}] \mathbf{n} \quad [1] $

In the previous expression, I applied the identity $\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{A \times B) = (\nabla \times A)\cdot B - (\nabla \times B)\cdot A}$.

Moreover, for any surface $\nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{n} = 0$. Thus, we obtain the following:

$ \nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} = - [ (\nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} )\cdot \mathbf{n}] \mathbf{n} \quad [2]$

Now, we can expand the term on the right hand side of the previous equation by using the first line of Equation [1], which is $ \nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} = [\nabla_\Gamma \cdot (\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{P})]\mathbf{n}$ :

$ [ (\nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} )\cdot \mathbf{n}] \mathbf{n} = \Big ( [\nabla_\Gamma \cdot (\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{P})]\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{n} \Big ) \mathbf{n} = \Big ( [\nabla_\Gamma \cdot (\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{P})] \Big ) \mathbf{n} = \nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} $

Then, evaluating in Equation [2], we get that $\nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} = 0$.

I am pretty sure this is wrong since I could define a vector $v$ on the $x-y$ plane as $v = < f(x,y), g(x,y)>$, where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions.

Then $\nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} = (\partial_x g - \partial_y f)\hat{z}$, which is not always zero.

Would you please let me find my error in the derivation I did?

Comment: How are you getting this line? $$[ (\nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} )\cdot \mathbf{n}] \mathbf{n} = \Big ( [\nabla_\Gamma \cdot (\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{P})]\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{n} \Big ) \mathbf{n}.$$ This makes no sense to me, and I am certain this is where your mistake lies.

Comment: I just edited the post to make it more clear. The identity $ \nabla_\Gamma \times \mathbf{P} = [\nabla_\Gamma \cdot (\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{P})]\mathbf{n}$ is derived by taking the dot product with $\mathbf{n}$ of the first line in Equation [1].

Comment: I was wrong. The issue is with [1]. We could adopt two conventions for surface curl: "inward" pointing is positive, or "outward" pointing is positive. Only one of these conventions satisfies the identity used in [1], I believe outward-positive. I suspect that your definition $$[\nabla_\Gamma\cdot(\mathbf n\times\mathbf f)]\mathbf n\tag{$*$}$$ is inward-positive and should really be notated something like $$\dot{\mathbf f}\times\dot\nabla_\Gamma=-\nabla_\Gamma\times\mathbf f.$$ If you could give a derivation/source for ($*$) then we would be able to determine if this is the case.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. The minus sign is usually ignored in these derivations for tangent vectors since it does not affect too much. In the end the curl is in the direction of $\mathbf{n}$, and that's what matters. However, for these expansions obviously it matters. Thank you so much!